# Is there a good way to perform SQL dump of MySQL database in DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, datagrip

I'm trying to use JetBrains DataGrip as my primary DB tool. However, I still find myself using SequelPro for SQL Dump. Here is why:

On a database level, I couldn't find any SQL dump functionality. The only options seems to be "copy DDL", which copies the schema, but not the content.

On a table level, sure, I can export data as SQL Inserts. But then it seems the only way to do so is to export it from each table separately, which is unacceptable. Another downside is, when exporting data as INSERT, it creates a separate INSERT statement for each row.

I tried to look for plugins, but couldn't find any. DataGrip users, if you came up with any solutions, please let me know. Sequel Pro works like a charm, but I really would love to use one database client at the end of the day.

PS. SSHing to a server and running sqldump is not an option for me, for various security reasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In 2016.2 there is some functionality, check like in screenshot.
2016.3 will be integrated with mysqldump.

[image: Dump menu]

Comment: Thanks @moscas, good to know it's on their roadmap. I checked out 2016.2, and while the functionality is there, it's still just a script that exports all the tables separately into separate files. Still better than nothing, and looking forward to 2016.3