# Can I use a line of code to tell Datagrip to dump the output?

Tags: postgresql, export-to-csv, datagrip

I'm trying to find a way to dump data in Datagrip directly from the code, so I don't have to always go and click on the button to export. Is there any command to do this? By going through their website most of the examples are using the "point and click" method. And I didn't see any discussion here, besides this on [Is there a good way to perform SQL dump of MySQL database in DataGrip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061236/is-there-a-good-way-to-perform-sql-dump-of-mysql-database-in-datagrip).

I wanted something similar to write.csv() in Python/R.

Comment: It is about technology, not a tool, isn't it?

Comment: @moscas well, yeah, kind of... should I delete the question because of this?